# How to apply a different multi-argument function to each row of a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, mapply

I have a data.table in the following sample format.

```
dt <- data.table(l = c("apple","ball","cat"),
                 m = c(1,2,3),
                 n = c("I ate apple", "I played ball", "cat ate pudding"))
```

I want to apply `sub` to a column (`n`) for each row with the pattern coming from another column (`l`). How would I do this?

The output I am looking for is,

```
              l m             n    o
       1: apple 1     I ate apple       I ate
       2:  ball 2   I played ball    I played
       3:   cat 3 cat ate pudding ate pudding
```

I have tried using the approach `mapply(do.call, list(sub), ...)` with the assignment operator within the data.table but the arguments to `sub` (pattern, replacement, string) need to be a nested list for `do.call` and I am stuck on how to write this properly.

Comment: why not just `dt[, Map(sub, l, '', n)]`? EDIT: that will give me a named vector/list, so what we actually want is to wrap the return in list `dt[, o := (Map(sub, l, '', n))]`

Comment: @Shape thank you! my approach seems unnecessarily complicated now. I was trying to come up with a method where, instead of `sub`, I could have a list of distinct functions. Your code does the job in my case, though. If you'd like to post it as an answer, please go ahead.

Comment: @Shape I agree you should post that. I'd go with `dt[, mapply(sub, sprintf(" ?%s ?", l), "", n, USE.NAMES = FALSE)]` -- handles the names issue and also the fact that the patterns may have spaces around them (that the OP presumably also wants to remove).

Comment: Should I edit the title of the question to make it more appropriate to what I am asking? I think the way I phrased it may be confusing as it isn't a different function in my case...

Comment: We can do `dt[, o := trimws(sub(paste(l, collapse="|"), "", n))]`

Comment: @akrun while that technically works on his example, if there are any regex specials in his substitution column, it could impact every row. I would say the regex `|` is probably unsafe. Doesn't even need to be a special, what if he's searching for another word there?

Comment: @Shape Yes, that could be true, but here the OP gave us an example to test

Comment: @akrun - I believe the whole point of the question is that the arguments for the function come on a row-by-row basis. There's really no way to escape the slowness in such a circumstance.

Comment: thanks for the answers! I was looking for something along the lines of a row-by-row approach, but the `collapse` approach would have been neat if my real data supported it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we want do a rowwise calculation, and return it defined as a new column `o`

`mapply` is definitely the right family of functions, but `mapply` (and `sapply`) will simplify their output out of a list before they return it. `data.table` loves lists. `Map` is just an expressive shortcut to `mapply(..., simplify = FALSE)` which does not modify the return.

The following does the calculation we're after, but it's still not quite right. (`data.table` interprets the list-output as separate columns)

```
> dt[, Map(sub, l, '', n)]
    apple      ball          cat
1: I ate  I played   ate pudding
```

So we want to go one further and wrap it in a list to get the output we're after:

```
>dt[, .(Map(sub, l, '', n))]
             V1
1:       I ate 
2:    I played 
3:  ate pudding
```

Now we can assign this using `:=`

```
> dt[, o := Map(sub, l, '', n)]
> dt
       l m               n            o
1: apple 1     I ate apple       I ate 
2:  ball 2   I played ball    I played 
3:   cat 3 cat ate pudding  ate pudding
```

EDIT: As was pointed out, this results in `o` being a list-column.

We can avoid this by using standard `mapply`, though I tend to prefer the one-size-fits-all approach of `Map` (Each row creates a single output, which goes in a list. Regardless of what that output looks like, this will always work, and then we can type-convert at the end.)

`dt[, o := mapply(sub, l, '', n)]`

Comment: That will make `dt$o` an embedded list, so I think `mapply` is actually more appropriate

Comment: true enough, should have checked my column classes, I still kind've like `Map` though, and then converting to character. I don't usually trust the simplifies. `Map`'s behavior is always the same. I'll add the other way though

Comment: You are wrong re "data.table loves lists." Data.table loves a list of columns and it *permits* columns that are lists, but the latter are messy to work with and always will be.

Comment: @Frank I was more considering lists vs. matrices... which can be a real danger when returning from the simplified apply family.  And if you know your data is safe from returning those types then it's much better than a list-column. However, I would nearly always do it with `Map` first, and then see if I can optimize by using a simplified `mapply`

Answer (score 1):

We can do a vectorized approach by `paste`ing the contents of 'l', use that as `pattern` argument in `sub` to remove the substring and create the new column 'o'

```
dt[, o := trimws(sub(paste(l, collapse="|"), "", n))]
dt
#       l m               n           o
#1: apple 1     I ate apple       I ate
#2:  ball 2   I played ball    I played
#3:   cat 3 cat ate pudding ate pudding
```